# Using Lambda to Upload to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I Created a lambda function that downloads data from S3 then preforms a merge and then re-uploads it back to S3 but i have been getting this

error {
  "errorMessage": "2020-05-18T23:23:27.556Z 37233f48-18ea-43eb-9030-3e8a2bf62048 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

***When I remove the lines between 45 and 58 it works just fine***

[image]
https://ideone.com/RvOmPS

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from io import StringIO # python3; python2: BytesIO 
import boto3
import s3fs
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
# Dataset 1
# loading the data
df1 = pd.read_csv("https://i...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/Minimum+Wage+Data.csv",encoding= 'unicode_escape')

# Renaming the columns.
df1.rename(columns={'High.Value': 'min_wage_by_law', 'Low.Value': 'min_wage_real'}, inplace=True)

# Removing all unneeded values.
df1 = df1.drop(['Table_Data','Footnote','High.2018','Low.2018'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.loc[df1['Year']>1969].copy()

# ---------------------------------

# Dataset 2
# Loading from the debt S3 bucket
df2 = pd.read_csv("https://i...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/USGS_Final_File.csv") 

#Filtering getting the range in between 1969 and 2018.
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Year']>1969].copy()
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Year']<2018].copy()
df2.rename(columns={'Real State Growth %': 'Real State Growth','Population (million)':'Population Mil'}, inplace=True)

# Cleaning the data
df2['State Debt'] = df2['State Debt'].str.replace(',', '')
df2['Local Debt'] = df2['Local Debt'].str.replace(',', '')
df2["State and Local Debt"] = df2["State and Local Debt"].str.replace(',', '')
df2["Gross State Product"] = df2["Gross State Product"].str.replace(',', '')

# Cast to Floating
df2[["State Debt","Local Debt","State and Local Debt","Gross State Product"]] = df2[[ "State Debt","Local Debt","State and Local Debt","Gross State Product"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

# --------------------------------------------
# Merge the data through an inner join.
full = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['State','Year'])
#--------------------------------------------
filename = '/tmp/'#specify location of s3:/{my-bucket}/
file= 'debt_and_wage' #name of file
datetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") #timestamp
filenames3 = "%s%s%s.csv"%(filename,file,datetime) #name of the filepath and csv file

full.to_csv(filenames3, header = True)

## Saving it on AWS

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='accesskeycantshare',aws_secret_access_key= 'key')

s3.meta.client.upload_file(filenames3, 'information-arch',file+datetime+'.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default [lambda execution timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html) is **3 seconds**. Please increase it to what suits your task:

> Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is **3 seconds**. The maximum allowed value is **900 seconds**.

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the timeout of your lambda function. The default behavior of a newly created function is to terminate after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody for the help, just did what increased the timeout and it worked just fine, I did it through here

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked out. But is 4 second OK? Its seems like at a borderline of what your functions needs? Maybe to be on the safe side, make it to 10s?

Answer (score 0):

IF the jobs size is big you can try increasing the memory of the function.
For now increase the timeout of the function.